# yarn add not adding the package to package.json with version 3.5.1

Tags: yarnpkg

I'm trying to add a package using yarn add <package_name>. It is not adding the package_name to the dependencies in package.json.

yarn version: 3.5.1
node version: 20.1.0

I don't see node_modules folder as well

[image]

[image]

[image]